# Multiple lines of text column not showing in Content query webpart sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, cqwp

I want to add custom column Document Description in CQWP for this I added below code in ItemStyle.xsl

> xsl:value-of select="@Document_x0020_Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"

In wepart I used below code

> property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Document_x0020_Description,Note

but even after doing this CQWP not showing its value, it is coming blank but when I do same steps for "Single line of text" type column then in that case all are workin fine.

Please let me know how to add Multiple lines of text column in CQWP

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the properties "DataMappingViewFields" and "DataMappings" in the webpart like:

```
<property name="DataMappings" type="string">LinkUrl:{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},FileRef,Lookup;|Description:{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},ShortComment,Text;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|Ingress:{C0ECDC73-85A2-478B-823D-B882219ACA8A},Ingress,Note;|</property>

<property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{94f89715-e097-4e8b-ba79-ea02aa8b7adb},Lookup;{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{691b9a4b-512e-4341-b3f1-68914130d5b2},Text;{C0ECDC73-85A2-478B-823D-B882219ACA8A},Note;</property>
```

The last property here called "Ingress" is a Note-field. Maybe this will make the field available in the xsl?